# Get text from WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, php, wysiwyg, quill

I have a quill I don't know how to get the data I typed inside the editor.

Here is what I did:

HTML here is how I initialize my Quill:

```
<div class="rui-quill"><span data-feather="chevron-down" class="rui-icon rui-icon-stroke-1_5 rui-quill-select-icon"></span>
  <div class="rui-quill-toolbar">
      <div class="ql-formats">
         <select class="ql-header"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="ql-formats">
         <button class="ql-bold"></button>
         <button class="ql-italic"></button>
         <button class="ql-underline"></button>
         <button class="ql-strike"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="ql-formats">
         <button class="ql-clean"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="ql-formats">
         <button type="button" class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
         <button type="button" class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="ql-formats">
         <button class="ql-link"></button>
      </div>
   </div>
<div class="rui-quill-editor" id="message"></div>
```

Javascript (Here is what I did to get the message)

```
$('#confirmsend').click(function(){
    var editor_content = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML;
    alert(editor_content);
});
```

Here is my script initialization

```
<script src="./assets/vendor/quill/dist/quill.min.js"></script>
```

and here is the image of my Quill editor

[image]

Comment: @YaakovAinspan nope I tried that already

Comment: @lawrenceagulto Hi. Yaakov Ainspan's comment expresses **exactly** what needs to be done to obtain Quill **data**. If not, what kind of data are you trying to get?